# What does -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] mean in a crash report and how to fix it

Tags: ios, swift, crash, report

I'm very confused about this. I have received many crash reports with the above message highlighted. My app never crashes for me, so I don't really know whats going on?

Any help would be much appreciated, and try to dumb it down for me, I'm very new to this.

Anything else you might need to answer this, just let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: Update your question with the complete stack trace of the crashing thread. Be sure the stack trace is symbolicated.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I don't even know how to upload a screenshot of it

Comment: You don't upload a screenshot. You copy and paste the text from the symbolicated crash log.